# Is there a way to iterate and compare dom elements in nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightwatch.js

[image]I'm trying to get two values from a site I'm automating. I iterate through an array of elements and try to compare the value of the dropdown to what is on the page to make sure they equal one another. One of the values can only be accessed by `.getValue()`. The other is accessed by `.getText()`. I would like to save the `result.value` of these callback functions and compare the results.

I've tried to `console.log` both of these values and I get them back, but I can't return anything from this callback function. I also can't seem to save it's value in a variable and return that either. I've tried looking to do it in plain javascript with `document.getElementById()` but that works for client-side javascript, not serverside like nodejs. Just trying to compare two values together

```js
for (let i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
  browser
    .element('css selector', `mat-nav-list > a:nth-child(${i})`,
      function(result) {
        if (result.value && result.value.ELEMENT) {
          browser.isVisible(`mat-nav-list > a:nth-child(${i})`,
            function(result) {
              if (result.value === true) {

                browser.click(`mat-nav-list > a:nth-child(${i})`)
                let chunkView = '#mat-input-0';
                let sideBar = `body > gps-app-root > div > div.sidebar-desktop > gps-app-sidebar-menu > div > div.product-list-wrap > mat-nav-list > a:nth-child(${i}) > div`

                browser.getValue(chunkView, function(result) {
                  chunkView = result.value
                  console.log(chunkView)
                })

                browser.getText(sideBar, function(result) {
                  console.log(result.value);
                })
              }
            })
        }
      })
  //.pause(2000)
  //.pause(10000)
}
```

When I loop through I would expect to get the two values sideBar `result.value` to equal `chunkView` `result.value`. Current output can only log the two separate values.

Comment: Do you want your assertion to come after `browser.getText()`?  I'm also guessing that `chunkView` isn't set yet by the time it gets to that assertion?

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you/your team just starting to use nightwatch? Are you bound to it, or could you switch to another test framework? And what client UI framework are you using (React, Angular, etc)?

Comment: We are currently bound to using nightwatch. Yes I want my assertion to come after browser.getText(). I need to do more testing to verify yoyur chunkView assertion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found if I nested .getValue() and .getText and assigned variables I was able to compare the two.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Nightwatch.js before, so I'm basing my answer on the assumption that `browser.click`, `browser.getValue`, and `browser.getText` run asynchronously, as that's fairly common with UI and UI test frameworks, and, if they did run synchronously, there would be no point in using callbacks.

You're probably going to want to get used to working with the [JavaScript `Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).  Since JavaScript engines are single-threaded, there is no way to spinlock/sleep while another thread handles some change (such as updating the UI after a click event).  A `Promise` allows you to get around this by working with callbacks and handling events behind the scenes.

You can then chain promises using `promise.then()` which pass the returned value to the next callback.

In your case, though, I would wrap the two functions that retrieve values in promises and then use [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).  This allows them to complete in any order which could improve performance.

```js
browser.isVisible(`mat-nav-list > a:nth-child(${i})`,
    function(result) {
        if (result.value === true) {
            browser.click(`mat-nav-list > a:nth-child(${i})`);
            let chunkView = '#mat-input-0';
            let sideBar = `body > gps-app-root > div > div.sidebar-desktop > gps-app-sidebar-menu > div > div.product-list-wrap > mat-nav-list > a:nth-child(${i}) > div`;

            let valPromise = new Promise(resolve => {
                browser.getValue(chunkView, resolve);
            });

            let textPromise = new Promise(resolve => {
                browser.getText(sideBar, resolve);
            });

            Promise.all([valPromise, textPromise]).then(([valueResult, textResult]) => {
                browser.assert.strictEqual(valueResult.value, textResult.value, 
                    `Server-side value '${value.result}' does not match client-side value '${text.result}'`);
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: So currently I'm getting an error when using client.assert. I researched a little bit because I'm doing this more on the server side with node and I changed client to console.assert. Now all I see is Assertion Failed. I like the Promise solution and it seems to make the most sense. Let me know if you figure anything else out. Please see the attached screenshot.

Comment: Yes, `client.assert` is probably failing because `client` isn't defined in your (or my) code, and actually it looks like I misused it in the first place, when I glanced at the api docs.  According to the docs (http://nightwatchjs.org/api#assertions) the assert object is an extension of nodejs's built-in assert object.  You're going to want to use `browser.assert.strictEqual` (https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_strictequal_actual_expected_message).  I'll update my answer.

Comment: It's also really unfortunate that nightwatch doesn't adhere to the node callback convention of returning an `err` argument first, and the remaining values after (https://gist.github.com/sunnycmf/b2ad4f80a3b627f04ff2). If it did, you could use `util.promisify` (https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) or a promise package like Bluebird to call `promisifyAll()` on `browser` (http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html). You could still do this using `util.promisify.custom`, but it might be more work than it's worth.

Comment: I did a little more research, and it looks like someone did the work of promisifying nightwatch already.  The project is called nightwatch-api.  https://github.com/mucsi96/nightwatch-api  I might use this myself.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `perform` method so that callbacks are ensured to have completed before the next command. (see https://github.com/nightwatchjs/nightwatch/wiki/Understanding-the-Command-Queue#the-perform-command)

Something like this

```js
browser.getValue(chunkView, function(result) {
  chunkView = result.value
  console.log(chunkView)
}).perform(function() {
  // here you have access to chunkView so you can compare it
  browser.getText(sideBar, function(result) {
    console.log(result.value);
    if (chunkView === result.value) {
      console.log('They are the same!');
    }
  })
});
```

---

or you could chain `perform` commands so that you can do the comparison at the end regarding the number of intermediate steps.

```js
let chunkView = '#mat-input-0',
    chunkViewResult;
let sideBar = `body > gps-app-root > div > div.sidebar-desktop > gps-app-sidebar-menu > div > div.product-list-wrap > mat-nav-list > a:nth-child(${i}) > div`,
    sideBarResult;

browser.getValue(chunkView, function(result) {
    chunkViewResult = result.value
    console.log(chunkView)
}).getText(sideBar, function(result) {
      sideBarResult = result.value
      console.log(sideBarResult);

}).perform(function() {
    if (chunkViewResult === sideBarResult) {
        console.log('They are the same!')
    }
})
```

Comment: So they seem to be the same yes, however, I find that this code doesn't even execute the if statement at the end.

Comment: @Jack if you are talking about the second code snippet, can you try the updated code?

Comment: @Jack i made some changes in the second code snippet in my answer. But the api project you mention might be a better aproach if it is maintained.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use .execute() from nightwatch and run any javascript you want in the page.

```
client.execute(
  function (data) { 
    // this is runned in browser
  },
  [what_you_pass_to_the_function_above_as_data], // multiple parameters = multiple elements in array
  function (result) {
    // result.status == -1 if error happend 
    // here you cand compare what you want... result.value is the returned things from the browser executed function.
  }
);
```